# child links in quick launch navigation in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Based on example in [SP.NavigationNode object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247080.aspx) for getting quick launch url and quick launch title

we have something like this

```
while (nodeEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var node = nodeEnumerator.get_current();
    nodeInfo += '{"title":"' + node.get_title() + '",' + '"link":"' + node.get_url() + '"},'; 
}
```

but if any of those navigation urls have any childs I don't know how to get that?

Comment: this question answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373931/child-links-in-quick-launch-navigation-in-sharepoint/34380419#34380419

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look solution i came up with for the same problem. Below is a snippet and has been created with angular defer.

Essentially, you will have to call the "get_Children" method on each item and reinitialize the item using ctx.load(). then push that item into an array.

One the array has been full formed, call the ctx.executeQueryAsync() function again and iterate through your array

```
               ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                    function () {
                        var navEnum = nav.getEnumerator();
                        var result = [];
                        while (navEnum.moveNext()) {
                            var obj = {};
                            var node = navEnum.get_current();
                            var props = node.get_objectData().get_properties();
                            var id = node.get_id();
                            obj = props;
                            obj.children = [];
                            itemArray.push(obj);
                            var children = node.get_children();
                            ctx.load(children)
                            result.push(children);

                        }

                        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

                            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                var resultsCount = result[i].get_count();
                                if (resultsCount > 0) {
                                    var resultEnum = result[i].getEnumerator();
                                    while (resultEnum.moveNext()) {
                                        var obj = {};
                                        var node = resultEnum.get_current();
                                        var props = node.get_objectData().get_properties();
                                        var id = node.get_id();

                                        itemArray[i].children.push(props)
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            deferred.resolve(itemArray)
                        }, function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(args.get_message()) })

                    }
```

Comment: first thanks for your answer , I tried to use that but I couldn't  :( but someone else from somewhere else had better solution

Comment: Please share the better solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373931/child-links-in-quick-launch-navigation-in-sharepoint/34380419?noredirect=1#comment56593189_34380419